# Implement query based property

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I've been trying to figure if it is possible to implement query based properties in Eloquent, such that the following data structure for example would allow having an `is_admin` property on the User model, which returns `true` or `false` depending on whether or not the user has been assigned the role named `Admin`.

Since relationships in some sense work like this, I figured it would be possible, but how exactly eludes me.

```
users
  int id
  string name

roles
  int id
  string name

user_roles
  int id
  int user_id
  int role_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code, but I'm pretty sure it will work:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'user_roles');
    }

    public function hasRole($roleName)
    {
        return count($this->roles()->where('name',$roleName)->get()) > 0;
    }

}
```

And then use it:

```
$user = User::find(1);
if ($user->hasRole('Amdin'))
{
    /// do something
}
```

Comment: How does the DB request flow look when doing this? Does it all work with one request as long as the request is done `->with('roles')`, even when fetching many users?

Comment: I've just realized that Eloquent fetches each lazy loaded relationship as a separate query (once per `with()`, not once per model). So this works (as does the answer below, which is essentially identical), but requires loading extra data before determining the value.

Answer (score 0):

not quite a property, but you could implement a $user->isAdmin() method in User like so:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    // check if the user has an admin role
    if ($this->roles()->where('name', '=', 'Admin')->count() > 0)
    {
        // return true if he does
        return true;
    }

    // return false if he doesn't
    return false
}
```

Alternatively you could create a 'is_admin' column in the User table as an Integer with a length of 1.  Set default to 0, if the user is an admin set to 1, then you could use $user->is_admin in boolean tests.

Comment: it works OK for single rows, but doing this for every user will result in far to many DB requests being performed.

My example is for roles as it was easier to explain, but what I'm really want to do is more akin to "has the currently authenticated user bookmarked this item".